# How to set Droplist Standard Fields to Read-Only for Non-Admin user

Tags: sitecore-client

I have restricted the "Context Menu" field to Read-Only for non-admin users.

[image]

However, it is still editable for non-admin. The text was grayed but can still click the droplist.
[image]

Any idea how to disable the droplist?

Comment: Did you give this permission on "Sitecore/Everyone" role?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you are looking for **droptree** to visible only for the admin user. Other users can see in read-only mode and should not able to browse the option.

If that's understanding is correct, then as mentioned by Gobinath, the solution will work, I've just quickly created a data setup and verified it, Please see if that's useful or correct.

Settings -
[image]

The result will look like this -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deny Write and File Write for everyone, this will disable drop down selection and other permissions in the field for all users in Sitecore except admin. 
So no additional security required for Sitecore\admin user, but if you have local admins and if required, then provide write access to "Sitecore Local Administrators".

[image]